# Jssor drag and drop not working

Tags: drag-and-drop, jssor

I've set up this slide some time ago and today, trying to fix some bugs, I updated the library code.

During some tests I noticed that the pc drag and drop doesn't work anymore, but the touch event does, but I'm not sure it worked before because it's been a while since I checked.

Is there something wrong?
Here's the code:

Image html Template:

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="url" />
    <div u="thumb">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url('url'); background-size: contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Slider.js:

```
var jssor_slider1;
    function getContentHeight(){
        return $(window).height()-$("#container").offset().top;
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
            $FillMode: 5,
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $ChanceToShow: 2
            },
            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,
                    $SpacingX: 8,
                    $Cols: 10,
                    $Align: 0
            }
        };
        $("#play_button").attr("state", "active");

        jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);


        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = $("#container").innerWidth();
            if (parentWidth){
                var windowHeight = getContentHeight()*0.83;
                var originalWidth = $("#slider1_container").width();
                var originalHeight = $("#slider1_container").height();
                var thumbHeight = originalHeight/6;
                originalHeight += thumbHeight;


                var scaleWidth = parentWidth;
                if (parentWidth / originalWidth > windowHeight / originalHeight) {
                    scaleWidth = Math.ceil((windowHeight / originalHeight )* originalWidth);
                }
                jssor_slider1.$SetScaleWidth(scaleWidth);
            }
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        function play(){
            jssor_slider1.$Play();
            $("#play_button").attr("state", "active");
            $("#play_button").one("click", pause);
        }
        function pause(){
            jssor_slider1.$Pause();
            $("#play_button").attr("state", "deactive");
            $("#play_button").one("click", play);
        }

        $("#play_button").one("click", pause);

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);

        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean `drag/drop`? What's your device/browser/version?

Comment: Does it happen on http://www.jssor.com?

Comment: @jssor with drag and drop I mean for example navigate through the thumb navbar grabbing it and moving it. I kinda figured out what's happening because in my work-desktop it works, but with my windows 8.1 laptop it doesn't, maybe because my laptop has the touchscreen option. I think that jssor detects that the device use touch events so it disable the click listener.

Comment: @jssor when i'll be at home I'll try on jssor.com

Comment: Many thanks! Please describe the problem in detail after that.

Comment: Same issue found on jssor.com

Comment: I think that your code detects that the device can use touch event so, to avoid double triggering, it disable the click/mouse events. In this case my device is a notebook, so it's preferable to use mouse events, but it has a Touchscreen, so it could use even touch events.

Comment: Thanks! Please send me your user agent string of your browser. Visit http://www.jssor.com/testcase/browser.html to get it.

Comment: I made some changes and worked out a test page. http://www.jssor.com/testcase/touch-mouse-drag-test.html Please have a test, thanks!

Comment: here's my User agent: 
userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
appName: Netscape
appVersion: 5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
IsSafari: false
IsOpera: false
IsChrome: true
IsFireFox: false
Version: 41
AppleWebKit Version: 537.36


any way the test works

Comment: Thanks! I think this bug has already been fixed, please test it on http://www.jssor.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a bug in the library, now with the help of jssor it's all fixed.